# how to setup Jest for a React Native app with Redux toolkit and typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

My team has been trying to implement unit testing for our React Native App using Jest Framework, but we have been encountering a lot of issues that we are not able to understand how to face.

Here is one of the components we are trying to test.
**recipe.test.ts**

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

import RicettaStep6 from '../src/pages/ricetta-new/ricetta-step6';
import {fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

describe('Sezione ingredienti', () => {
  test("correctly converts ingredients's text", () => {
    let { queryByTestId } = render(<RicettaStep6/>);
    let firstInput = queryByTestId('input-ingrediente0');

    fireEvent.changeText(firstInput, '20g di farina');

    expect(firstInput.value).toBe('20 grammi farina');
  });
});
```

Here is my jest config in jest.config.js
**jest.config.js**

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require('ts-jest/presets');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
      diagnostics: {
        warnOnly: true
      }
    }
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node']
};
```

Here is the error that we are continously getting
[image]

What can be the issue? And if not, how do you implement the unit testing for your application?